# Connect on-premise Virtual Machine to Azure Active Directory

Tags: virtual-machine, azure-ad

I want to include on-premise Virtual Machine into Azure Active Directory. I don't have much idea how to implement this. Kindly let me know the steps to perform this.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with that connection? Should AAD-Only users be able to access your OnPremises SharePoint?

Comment: Yes, I want only AAD users to acess on-premise Virtual Machine. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you go the "wrong" direction from Microsoft's perspective. Integrating OnPremises Users to SP Online works like a charm. The way back is much more complicated.

You need to configure a TrustedIdentityTokenIssuer (TST) in SharePoint. This will make SharePoint trust another source for identities in addition to OnPremises ActiveDirectory.

- Set up OnPremises ADFS and add it as an Application in Azure AD
- Add Azure AD as an Identity Provider in ADFS
- Create Relying Party in SharePoint and Add Pass Thru Rule
- Create SPTrustedIdentityTokenIssuer in SharePoint

The whole process is described here in detail (skip step 1 in the blog as you want to enable AAD-Only users):
[Using Azure AD as an Identity Provider with ADFS for SharePoint 2013](https://samlman.wordpress.com/2015/03/05/using-azure-ad-as-an-identity-provider-with-adfs-for-sharepoint-2013/)

Integrating a TST into SharePoint comes with a lot of [drawbacks](https://www.google.de/search?source=hp&q=sharepoint%20fba%20drawbacks) and more complexity. Link is for FormsBasedAuthentication (FBA), but those drawbacks also apply to a TST. So test this scenario excessive and then decide if it is really the answer to your needs.